# how to rollback an interrupted deploy to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework

I interrupted a play framework deploy to gae

I deployed it with

```
play gae:deploy --gae=$GAE_PATH
```

And press ctrl-c in the middle of it

Now, when I try to redeploy it, I get the following error:

```
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=playdoces&version=20111007&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user opensas is already in progress for app: s~playdoces, version: 20111007. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg1441845586056774629.log] for further information.
```

I tried with

```
/home/sas/devel/gae/bin/appcfg.sh rollback
```

but there's no such option

any idea?

---

In the end, I've just created another version and set it as default

But I'd like to know if there's some way to cancel the previous deploy

Answer (score 12):

it is simple as:

`mvn appengine:rollback`

Comment: it is not that simple. I installed maven, and now it gives an error because the appengine package is not setup for it.

Comment: this works assuming we have setup the appengine management using maven so commands like mvn appengine:update work. Real time saver!

Answer (score 3):

Go one directory above your application and try with:

```
appcfg.sh rollback your_application_directory_name
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got a "Bad configuration" error, "could not find playdoces/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml", so I tried with "rollback playdoces/war", and then I get the error: "Caused by: playdoces/war/WEB-INF/web.xml (No such file or directory)"... I think we are getting close...

Comment: tried this, got 400 bad request error. no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the `<play_install>/modules/<gae_module>/bin` directory and edit the **commands.py** so that it includes the **rollback** command:

```
if command == "gae:rollback":
    print '~'
    print '~ Performing Rollback'
    print '~ ---------'

    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('%s/bin/appcfg.cmd rollback %s' % (gae_path, war_path))
    else:
        os.system('%s/bin/appcfg.sh rollback %s' % (gae_path, war_path))

    print "~ "
    print "~ Done!"
    print "~ "
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Run this like `play gae:rollback --gae=$GAE_PATH` then run your deploy again. Works for me with the same issue. I'll add a request to get this added to the module.

Comment: shoudn’t`os.system`supposed to be disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

First download and install the [app engine sdk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en) if you don't have it already. In case you are using Android Studio the following command will do it:

```
/path-to-appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.28/bin/appcfg.sh rollback /path-to-your-project/backend-module-folder/src/main/webapp/
```

Or put differently, what you need to do is to point it to the directory that has the 'WEB-INF' folder in it.

Comment: You need to have in your PATH the appengine-java-sdk. Or call it with it's path. For example: 
/path-to-appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.28/bin/appcfg.sh rollback /path-to-your-project/backend-module-folder/src/main/webapp/